# Showing deleted user status makes some review queue audits too obvious

Tags: bug, review-audits, deleted-accounts

I was just given [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3948957) in the Low Quality queue.

I neglected to get a screencap of the audit *as it was presented*, but the fact that the user was deleted was very obvious - no link, no gravatar, grey name.

The content itself is pretty obvious commercial canned luncheon meat product and it otherwise belonged in the queue as an appropriate audit.

Either:

1. Contributions from deleted users should be excluded from the audit pool, or
2. The fact that the user has been deleted should be hidden from the audit UI by linkifying the name, or
3. The audit should be attributed to another user like is done in some other audits.

Preferably 1, as it seems the most sane, and preferably not 3 because that's kind of silly anyway.

Comment: It will still catch robo reviewers.

Comment: Isn't that what the user looks like on migrated questions, if he hasn't established himself on this site yet?

Comment: In this specific case, I suspect that it was a user destruction as a result of spam flags.